# How to make totals of the datatable cells and construct a new column in that datatable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datacolumn

There are three columns in the datatable

```
Amount Commission Others
1000   200        100
2000   100        200
```

Now I want to build another column based on these three columns name `totalAmount` that is the sum of these three columns like the column will be

```
totalAmount
1300
2300
```

I got the records of the three columns `Amount,Commission and Others` and based on those columns I have a need of adding a new column in that datatable.We can manuall fetch and make total and add a new column in that datatable but is there any other good and short way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) property.

You can add a new DataColumn to your table, and set its Expression to "Amount + Commission + Others". It'll be calculated at runtime.

Comment: @Matt Hamilton,Would this add only column or records also ?

Comment: It won't add records. It's a column whose value is computed using other columns. You'll get a new value for every existing row.

Comment: Really? How about TableExtractedFromFile.Columns.Add("totalAmount", typeof(int), "Amount + Commission + Others"); ?

Comment: Are you doing this before or after you populate the table? I can't even remember if it matters, to be honest. Haven't used DataTable for years.

Comment: @Matt Hamilton,It works. But If I do like there is three columns A,B and C.  Now if do I `table.columns["A"].expression = "A+B+C";` then it gives error like **Cannot set Expression property due to circular reference in the expression.** then what is the solution of that ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't set a column to an expression that includes itself.

Comment: @Matt Hamilton,But sir, If I want to make addition of the values of three columns like column A,B,C and want to store those values in the column A the what should I do?

Comment: @Matt Hamilton,Even I copy of the column A and add new column AA then B+C+AA then also it gives same error.